# Building math theory on absurd axioms - reducing math to logic

Tags: logic, philosophy

I know similar questions have been asked and i know my terminology might be wrong but I am trying to come to an answer to whether math can be derived from logic. Wikipedia defines logic as use and study of valid reasoning and I assume something "logical" is defined as something that is consistent with this valid reasoning. There are few things here that trouble me. The term "valid reasoning" can be rather subjective and broad. Since logic is not a thing, but more of a process, I'm not sure how to define it as objective or subjective but regardless of that, the term "valid reasoning" is subjective. Is it even possible for humans to define that term?

Now, taking all this into consideration, I would come to think it is possible to define a mathematical theory or a whole branch  of math based on some absurd ( what troubles me again is that even the term "absurd" is subjective) axioms we define. Now if we use this axioms to define a theory, wouldn't that mean by the concept of inference that the whole theory is absurd. Does this mean it can't be derived from logic or does it just mean we don't know how to do it.

I am sorry if i made any major mistakes or used incorrect definitions and terms, but the whole concept of logic puzzles me, especially the fact that it is considered a science.

Comment: As you said : "absurd" is **not** a precise word. For the "mainstream" mathematics, what is "forbidden" is to start a theory with some contradictory axioms. But as long as you avoid contradictions, if "absurd" means : "denail of some well-received or common used assumption", nothing prevents you from assuming them and ... see what happens. The real issue is : are those "absurd" assumptions something which lead you to new/interesting facts/discoveries or not ?

Comment: About the definition of **logic**, the answer is not easy. In general, we can say that the *science* of logic aims at characterizing in a precise way exactly what amounts to be a "valid reasoning". If we agree on this, we can say taht an argument is valid if it follows the (precisely defined) rules of logic. If the conclusion of an argument is not commonly understood as a valid conclusion from the premises of the argument, we say that we have committed a *fallacy*, i.e. that we have "misused" some rule of logic.

Comment: Well yes, we could use that definition of absurd and if we do, another questions arises: Does that new-made theory have to be "useful" and applied to real world and if not, can we prove that there isn't a parallel universe in which this theory is applicable to real world. Now, i know that by including this parallel universe thing, I am just playing with words and crossing the boundaries of our universe. That put aside, your statement involving the term "rules of logic" makes me thing that logical reasoning IS subjective.

Comment: That is, if the majority of men were madmen, something they find logical would maybe be absurd for us, but then, since they are the majority, they would think we are the madmen. I've gone far away from the question ..

Comment: I do not agree about "logical reasoning IS subjective", but it is a fact that in the field of formal (and mathematical) logic there are some school of thinking (see [Intuitonism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/)) which do not agree with the "mainstream" mathematicians on some key "logic law". Thus 100% consensus on them is not available.

Comment: Last comment, about "Does this mean it can't be derived from logic". Last century a mathematico-phylosophical project of "deriving" all of math from logic alone was undertaken: see [Logicism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logicism/). We can say that it never succeeded. But the "usual" way of developing a math theory deriving *by logic* theorems from axioms in **not** so: we have to postulate axioms, which usually are not truth of logic.

Comment: Yes, I may have acted harshly upon saying that logical reasoning is subjective and I do see what you are trying to say here. Yes, "we have to postulate axioms, which usually are not truth of logic" was exactly what i was aiming at since some resources ( not very scientific though, more like forum discussions) tried convincing me otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Consider the "mother of all math theory" : Euclid's geometry with its [5th postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate) saing that : "If a line segment intersects two straight lines forming ...". We have no reason to believe that it is a truth of logic; in fact, non-Euclidean geometries show us that we can assume some "absurd" postulate denying the 5th and no contradiction arises. More : relativistic physics uses them with success. Conclusion : do not be afraid of "absurd" ...

Comment: Trying to link together some of the threads of the above discussion : let $\Sigma$ the set of Euclid's postulates and let $\varphi$ the Pythagoras' theorem. Then, the sentence : "if $\Sigma$, then $\varphi$" **is** a *logical truth*.

Comment: You might be over-thinking this. Ordinary true-or-false logic, as you will learn with experience, works remarkably well. If there are any "inconsistencies", it is only inconsistent with common usage (or misuse), e.g. confusing implication with causality. To do mathematics, you will also need some kind of set theory and maybe some additional axioms for, say, the natural numbers (see Peano). I don't think you really need to worry much about Godel's notion of incompleteness if that has been bothering you. It has not proven be a serious constraint on the work of most if not all mathematicians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid reasoning in ultimate case is a convention.

The general convention for valid reasoning is that it dont fall on contradiction (however Im not sure that this condition can be proved for all logical systems),i.e, the system must be [consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency).

In a more broad sense "dont fall in contradiction" means that the system to measure something give to us information.

The axioms can be as "absurd" as you want... but they need to be consistent to be useful.